# How to renumber GPT partitions on an umounted disk?

Tags: partition, gpt, gdisk

I tried to sort (renumber) partitions on `/dev/sdb` via terminal, using `gdisk` from the operating system (running on `/dev/sda`) and none of the `sdb` partitions mounted but the only option I get is `[-l]` which lists options the option I'm trying to use.

```
root@arch-bill /home/bill # lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
|-sda1   8:1    0  15.6G  0 part /
|-sda2   8:2    0 915.9G  0 part /home
`-sda3   8:3    0     2M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-sdb1   8:17   0     2M  0 part 
|-sdb2   8:18   0     4G  0 part 
|-sdb3   8:19   0    16G  0 part 
|-sdb4   8:20   0    60G  0 part 
`-sdb6   8:22   0   1.8T  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
root@arch-bill /home/bill # blkid
/dev/sdb1: PARTUUID="c1073e4b-fc00-4f02-8b81-6f17b8a188c4" 
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="var" UUID="62921c0a-5d34-464d-8a7a-2ff46ad8f12b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c350316a-0bd8-4e82-8597-123553977f99" 
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="rootbkp" UUID="c245c20e-d503-4b61-aaaf-060aae1b21d4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b1f391db-de37-479c-8b44-ff27f3bd6aa5" 
/dev/sdb4: LABEL="snapster" UUID="8fef4e0a-efd4-455b-b484-83bd4500161f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="02801cd9-3fe5-4814-9b92-c4c83b86173d" 
/dev/sdb6: LABEL="homebkp" UUID="51d73ac7-fd96-4ac1-b4f3-4abf6bc4936b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="481ae7d0-228f-4979-8949-befbd498534b" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="91865df2-0841-42f5-80f3-a5133976e70f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="48dc34cb-e791-4838-b9f2-2fe2b2cced33" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="e5743a89-13ed-4c96-b39d-78cb6478fb72" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4156cbf2-2a2d-47ae-87cf-99c14cf8f2c2" 
/dev/sda3: PARTUUID="8669392a-663e-4e15-bc63-a6a5e95c97ad" 

root@arch-bill /home/bill # gdisk -s /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Usage: gdisk [-l] device_file
1 
root@arch-bill /home/bill # gdisk -l /dev/sdb                                                                                                                                                                                          :(
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 3907029168 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 0645408C-0374-4357-8663-D2A3512E07BD
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907029134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 4204653 sectors (2.0 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048            6143   2.0 MiB     EF02  
   2            8192         8396799   4.0 GiB     0700  
   3         8398848        41953279   16.0 GiB    0700  
   4        41955328       167786495   60.0 GiB    0700  
   6       167788544      3902834687   1.7 TiB     0700  
1 root@arch-bill /home/bill #
```

Answer (score 12):

`gdisk` only has the one command line option (`-l`), to list the partition table and then quit. All of the other operations are conducted interactively from within `gdisk`. See [Rod Smith's walkthrough](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html) for some more context.

Essentially, though, you want to just use the command `# gdisk /dev/sdb` and then, at the prompt, use the `s` command to sort the partition entries. From `man gdisk`:

> s
>       Sort partition entries. GPT partition numbers need not match the order of partitions on the disk. If you want them to match, you can use this
>               option.  Note that some partitioning utilities sort partitions whenever they make changes. Such changes will  be  reflected  in  your  device
>               filenames, so you may need to edit /etc/fstab if you use this option.

You should also, before you begin, read Rod's page on [Repairing GPT Disks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html), just in case things head south during the operation...

Comment: ok, sdb is a backup drive with the partitions listed so its not bootable or written to, i manually mount a partition and then rsync to it when i need to backup sda, so filenames shouldn't be an issue correct?

Comment: @BillV That depends on what you are trying to do, but it sounds like a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

To sort partitions on `/dev/sdX`:

```
#sgdisk -s /dev/sdX
```

Comment: But why would you modify your partition table, just to make things look tidy?

Comment: @Jeremy Boden Because correctly ordered partitions prevents confusion and makes it easier to remember which partition is which.

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution with using `fdisk` over `gdisk`, which I just tested:

[According to this](https://journalxtra.com/linux/how-to-reorder-linux-drive-partition-numbers/):

> To reorder the Linux drive partition numbers for device sdc, all we
> need to do is open a terminal…
>
> ```
> type
>
> sudo fdisk /dev/sdc
>
> then
>     press “x” to enter Expert Mode
>     press “f” to fix the drive order
>     press “i” to ignore the warning (if it shows)
>     press “w” to write changes to the disk
>     press “r” to leave expert mode *(forgotten by the author)*
>     press “q” to  quit fdisk
> ```
>
> It’s that simple.
>
> Replace `/dev/sdc` with the name of the device you wish to reorganize
> partition numbers on.
>
> Now check the drive partition naming order by typing `sudo fdisk -l`
> into a terminal.

Comment: Perfect that works, you just have to press "r"  before "w"  to exit expert mode and then write.  "w" also automatically exists `fdisk`so no nieed for "q" at the end.  Maybe is just a newer version of fdisk, but thanks for this solution

Answer (score 1):

What about using sfdisk?

- Backup:
  `sfdisk -d /dev/sdb > disc1.sfdisk # Create also a backup file too`
- Edit the text file like this:

  - Rearrange the entries as you wish
  - then finally renumber the partitions
- Restore modified partition data:
  `sfdisk /dev/sdb < disc1.sfdisk`
- Example - Before:

Check the partition name how it is unordered (`"... name=..."`).

```
label: gpt
label-id: DBBC346B-516E-4EAF-BB5B-61810EF2E682
device: /dev/sdb
unit: sectors
first-lba: 34
last-lba: 4000797326

/dev/sdb1 : start=        2048, size=      204800, type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, uuid=7528D784-12C1-48D3-B94B-9CEF6D12E0A3, name="EFI system partition"
/dev/sdb2 : start=      206848, size=       32768, type=E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE, uuid=13D17776-9E43-42E2-ADD4-26D34E27B010, name="Microsoft reserved partition"
/dev/sdb3 : start=      239616, size=   203537112, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=CE13B309-40B7-44AF-A239-3129259BB2B2, name="Basic data partition"
/dev/sdb4 : start=   203778048, size=     1021952, type=DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC, uuid=8B6DA26A-8A07-4523-B2EE-46797EF42E40, attrs="RequiredPartition"
/dev/sdb5 : start=   204800000, size=   204800000, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=4F9359C9-34E9-4A8E-858A-058095DC63C1, name="Basic data partition"
/dev/sdb6 : start=   417988608, size=     4194304, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=3B752CBD-A0A9-4081-8939-E5B1921E2FFA, name="boot3"
/dev/sdb8 : start=   422182912, size=     8093696, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=9FA26BDA-4D93-455B-9D14-538DD27AF1CB, name="boot4"
/dev/sdb9 : start=   430276608, size=    70041600, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=1958F11E-1EE3-48F0-854F-B338072709FD, name="ubuntu1"
/dev/sdb10 : start=   500318208, size=    81162240, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=F7A0CFE8-1C81-4C23-8888-B8A6E3B63140, name="ubuntu2"
/dev/sdb11 : start=   409600000, size=     4193360, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=162818DD-E6DB-45AE-8A92-C8477F337AC0, name="boot1"
/dev/sdb12 : start=   581480449, size=    61439999, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=A8539116-B7DF-4282-9D31-5B87E1ADF41A, name="ubuntu3"
/dev/sdb13 : start=   642920448, size=    61440000, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=DD154362-1D49-464A-A17F-9077D42A5A6B, name="ubuntu4"
/dev/sdb15 : start=   413794304, size=     4194304, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=59BF449B-AB9A-487E-AA55-B47D6446E1FB, name="boot2"
```

Now edit the file by shifting the entries up or down and reassign sdb[n] numbers.
I chose for booting devices 1x and the corresponding linux partitions with 2x numbers:
And do not change the data after after the start=....!
After editing:

```
label: gpt
label-id: DBBC346B-516E-4EAF-BB5B-61810EF2E682
device: /dev/sdb
unit: sectors
first-lba: 34
last-lba: 4000797326

/dev/sdb1 : start=        2048, size=      204800, type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, uuid=7528D784-12C1-48D3-B94B-9CEF6D12E0A3, name="EFI system partition"
/dev/sdb2 : start=      206848, size=       32768, type=E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE, uuid=13D17776-9E43-42E2-ADD4-26D34E27B010, name="Microsoft reserved partition"
/dev/sdb3 : start=      239616, size=   203537112, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=CE13B309-40B7-44AF-A239-3129259BB2B2, name="Basic data partition"
/dev/sdb4 : start=   203778048, size=     1021952, type=DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC, uuid=8B6DA26A-8A07-4523-B2EE-46797EF42E40, attrs="RequiredPartition"
/dev/sdb5 : start=   204800000, size=   204800000, type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, uuid=4F9359C9-34E9-4A8E-858A-058095DC63C1, name="Basic data partition"
/dev/sdb11 : start=   409600000, size=     4193360, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=162818DD-E6DB-45AE-8A92-C8477F337AC0, name="boot1"
/dev/sdb12 : start=   413794304, size=     4194304, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=59BF449B-AB9A-487E-AA55-B47D6446E1FB, name="boot2"
/dev/sdb13 : start=   417988608, size=     4194304, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=3B752CBD-A0A9-4081-8939-E5B1921E2FFA, name="boot3"
/dev/sdb14 : start=   422182912, size=     8093696, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=9FA26BDA-4D93-455B-9D14-538DD27AF1CB, name="boot4"
/dev/sdb21 : start=   430276608, size=    70041600, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=1958F11E-1EE3-48F0-854F-B338072709FD, name="ubuntu1"
/dev/sdb22 : start=   500318208, size=    81162240, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=F7A0CFE8-1C81-4C23-8888-B8A6E3B63140, name="ubuntu2"
/dev/sdb23 : start=   581480449, size=    61439999, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=A8539116-B7DF-4282-9D31-5B87E1ADF41A, name="ubuntu3"
/dev/sdb24 : start=   642920448, size=    61440000, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=DD154362-1D49-464A-A17F-9077D42A5A6B, name="ubuntu4"
```

- Restore `sfdisk /dev/sdb < disc1.sfdisk`, refresh devices in GParted and check if the numbering is ok for you